# Creating a new record returns NoMethodError due to missing method that isn't being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've been working on a project with a has_many :through relationship between a Story and a Stack model, joined by Anthologies. I recently tweaked something that has broken the create method for new stories, but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it. When I go to add a story, I get the following error:

```
**NoMethodError in StoriesController#create**
undefined method `stack_id' for #<Story:0x1035968a8>
```

What's weird is that the create method makes no reference to 'stack_id'. In fact, it's pretty out of the box:

```
def create
  @story = Story.new(params[:story])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @story.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Story was successfully created.'
      format.html { redirect_to(@story) }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @story, :status => :created, :location => @story }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @story.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I thought maybe it had something to do with the routes, as they support accessing stories both directly and nested in stacks. But I've tried a number of variations and nothing seems to make a difference.

```
map.resources :stories, :member => {:rate => :post}  
map.resources :anthologies
map.resources :stacks, :has_many => :stories do |stack|
  stack.resources :stories
end
```

I'm clearly not understanding something about how objects are getting saved here. Any ideas on how I can solve this problem? I'm completely lost on what to do next. I've added the console output below in case it's helpful.

Thanks.

```
Processing StoriesController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-11-17 21:45:29) [POST]
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"save", "story"=>{"body"=>"sgfhsfgh", "title"=>"asdfa", "user_id"=>"1", "summary"=>"adfgdfhg"}, "action"=>"create", "authenticity_token"=>"1yws3Fs108kPSUS2W5SM1GFaiRqfiWhDbzDWstfoDCA=", "controller"=>"stories"}
  User Load (0.3ms)   SELECT "users".id FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 1) LIMIT 1

NoMethodError (undefined method `stack_id' for #<Story:0x1035968a8>):
  (eval):13:in `send'
  (eval):13:in `scope_condition'
  app/controllers/stories_controller.rb:58:in `create'
  app/controllers/stories_controller.rb:57:in `create'

Rendered rescues/_trace (90.0ms)
Rendered rescues/_request_and_response (0.3ms)
Rendering rescues/layout (internal_server_error)
```

Adding Model code by request, but it's pretty generic has_many :through...

```
has_many :anthologies
has_many :stories, :through => :anthologies
```

and

```
has_many :anthologies
has_many :stacks, :through => :anthologies
```

Comment: Can you show us the model code? I'm guessing Story has `belongs_to :stack`

Comment: Updated the original post to include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your routes I'd expect your stories table has a stack_id and the model has something like:

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :stack
  ..
end
```

Do you have a stack_id field in the stories table?

Comment: Nope. Stories and Stacks have has_many relationships :through Anthologies, which has stack_id as a column. I just can't figure out why it's trying to call that when I'm trying to create a Story without any relationship to a Stack.

Comment: The I suspect rails is not handling the has_many :through with the resources. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282127/rails-map-resources-with-has-many-through-doesnt-work/805948#805948 for an explanation and possible avenues to try.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out that it was conflicting with the acts_as_list plugin -- which only goes to show that I wasn't doing myself any favors by abbreviating the models here....